# Intercepting and Injecting in the Windows Message Loop

Tags: c, winapi, message-queue

We are using a poorly designed Windows engineering application in our office that does not allow importing of model definition data (as most other applications do). We can spend literally 1.5 weeks pointing and clicking in the GUI adding nodes, elements, etc. I will call this poorly written application "X".

So, would it be possible to write a parent application (I code C, C# & know how to read Petzold/Win32 a bit) that essentially would fire up this application "X" and intercept and inject windows messages into it's loop, so say, I could automatically fill in winform fields, and at least see what messages are being passed around? That way I could possibly script part of the repetitive elements of the GUI.

Thanks for any potential leads and starting points.

-jdrago

Comment: I have written many windows applications that do not use anything called _model definition data_.  What is it?, and I am curious, give some examples of most other applications.

Comment: There's an existing (open source) application called AutoHotkey that a lot of people seem to use for things like this - it might save reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You might be able to use AutoIt as well

Comment: You can also use the Spy++ tool, comes with Visual Studio, which is quite helpful for inspecting window messages.

Comment: If you want to create your own, (i.e. create a message loop) Here is  ***[a microsoft API approach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***

Comment: This is a job for UI Automation. C# has some really nice classes predefined for doing this. (See `System.Windows.Automation`.)

Comment: ryyker: The class of applications I am talking about are nonlinear finite element programs, in particular earthquake engineering. So when I refer to model definition data I am talking about a model of a building that consists of nodes, material properties, section properties, element connectivity, etc. Some of the big players are OpenSEES (free), LSDYNA, SAP2000. In those applications you (can) create an input file, or in the case of SAP2000 actually read in tables from a database. Regards, jdrago